# Can a python script access variables defined in an interactive session?

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

So, for instance, I'm in an ipython session, and I have a variable,

```
var = [3,5,6]
```

defined in the ipython session, that I want to do something with by running a script, e.g.:

```
# my_script
plot(var)
```

so I want typing

```
%run my_script.py
```

from the interactive session to plot var, as if I had typed:

```
plot(var)
```

within the interactive session.

Is this possible?  How?

Comment: If you define functions in your script and want to call them on variables in your session, you can do `import scriptname` (assuming `scriptname.py`) and then call `scriptname.plot(var)`, or similar.

Comment: That's not really what I'm after.  I just want to make my script behave exactly as if it's contents were copy/pasted into the session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, from the [run command documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-run): if you use `%run -i` it will run the script in your existing interactive session's namespace instead of a clean one, so it will have access to defined variables.

If you want similar in the standard python shell, you can run it with [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile): `execfile('my_script.py')`

Comment: Is something similar possible in python (no ipython)?